# Merging multiple csv files by the same column

Tags: python

I have a program which should merge multiple csv files

```
def merge( csv_output_path):
    os.chdir("output/filtered")

    all_filenames = "output/filtered/filtered.csv"
    extension = "csv"
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob( 'output/filtered/filtered.csv')]

    #combine all files in the list
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

    #combine all files in the list
    combined_csv = pd.concat(map([pd.read_csv(file) for file in all_filenames ]), axis=1, join='outer').sort_index()
    #export to csv
    combined_csv.to_csv( "MergedFiles.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

The code above does not join all these files by column. How can I join all these files that have only one column in common `timestamps`.

#### `fileA.csv`

[image]

#### `fileB.csv`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: I've tried using the pd.merege method but i think because I have a lot of  files it takes a lot longer to merge two files at once

Comment: By the way, all_filenames is being defined three times, and the value is discarded without any effect the first two times (removing the first two lines with all_filenames would have no effect on your function).